# bitwise operation and stuffing bytes together

Tags: c, winapi

is there a easy way to form a long long variable from 8 consecutive bytes....

```
TotalSectors = sector[0x28]|
               sector[0x28+1] << 8 |
               sector[0x28+2] << 16 |
               sector[0x28+3] << 24 |
               sector[0x28+4] << 32 | 
               sector[0x28+5] << 40 |
               sector[0x28+6] << 48 |
               sector[0x28+7] << 56;
```

Where TotalSectors is a long long variable....

I am working on windows platform and win32 api is my main choice..... any existing macro for this work would be helpful....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You may be stuffing bytes together, but that doesn't mean you have to stuff the code together.  Don't hate whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Endianness is good.  So just cast:

```
 TotalSectors = *(long long*)&sector[0x28];
```

Comment: Just take care about alignment - it's good for the index in the example, but if that changes then the alignment might become an issue.

Comment: I don't get the alignment issue, the Titanium has sunk.  Didn't it?  What other gimpy core is left that can run Windows?

Comment: I thought that alignment was an issue on x64, but on closer check, it's not.  There's always the future, though - right?

Answer (score 1):

what about a for loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
  TotalSectors |= sector[0x28+i]<<(8*i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already written the easy way out, so why not simply make it an inline function?